# Building crop recommender system with past cultivation data not with ratings

Tags: python, machine-learning-model, recommender-system

I am planning to create a Crop recommendation system for farmers using the past ten years' crop cultivation data. it is a mobile application. whenever a farmer selects his location, the system will recommend three crops based on the location's soil factors and climate factors. I have past crop cultivation data with soil and climate factor. But I don't have farmer ratings for the particular crop cultivation.

[image: This is my dataset]

which technique is suitable to build a recommendation system for this problem collaborative or content? or suggest any other method? how can I implement it?